# Http Post in laravel using fetch api giving TokenMismatchException

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fetch-api

I am trying to make a http post using fetch api. Even though I am sending the token, I am getting error **TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php** . How can I make the call using fetch api? (I also tried with jQuery ajax and its working perfectly)  Heres the fetch api code

```
      var URL = $("#form").attr("action");
      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
      var group_id = $(this).val();
  fetch(URL, {
       method: 'post',
       mode: 'no-cors',
       body: JSON.stringify({
           'csrf-token': token,
           'group_id': group_id
       })
     }).then(function(response){
           return response.json();
       })  .then(function(json){



       })
         .catch(function(error){


         });
```

I have added token in form like this

```
<form id="form" action="{{ url('api/getcoursebygroup') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
  </form>
```

This jQuery ajax call is working fine :

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  URL,
          data: { "group_id" : group_id, "_token" : token },
          dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function (result) {

        if(result.code == 1){



        }


      });
```

jQuery ajax call headers

[image]

Fetch api call headers

[image]

Comment: Which laravel version? For 5.* its should be `csrf-token` instead of `_token`

Comment: hm... can u compare xhr of both requests in dev tools?

Comment: its working with _token rather than csrf-token when i make jquery ajax call I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: sorry it was my bad. I'm confused it with `meta` name

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to make it work.

There were 2 changes I have to make

1) Fetch Api don't use cookie by default. So to make it use cookie I added

`credentials: "same-origin"`

2)the data need to be submitted in Form data format rather than json

so here's my working code

```
       var URL = $("#form").attr("action");
       var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
       var group_id = $(this).val();

      fetch(URL, {
       method: 'post',
       credentials: "same-origin",
       body: new FormData(document.getElementById('form'))
     }).then(function(response){
           return response.json();
       })  .then(function(json){

         // change course

       })
         .catch(function(error){


         });
```

Comment: Where is the declared token used?

Answer (score 31):

I may be late to the party but this works too

```
    fetch("/audio/signed", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "X-CSRF-Token": $('input[name="_token"]').val()
      },
      method: "post",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: "value"
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 14):

**index.blade.php**

```php
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**app.js**

```js
const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;

function orderPost(order) {
    fetch('/orders', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(order),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(text => {
        return console.log(text);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

**OrderController.php**

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = $request->json('user_id');
    $order->item_list = $request->json('item_list');
    $order->leave_note = $request->json('leave_note');
    $order->total = $request->json('total');
    $order->save();

    $response = [
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'order stored',
];

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: Hello @umutyerebakmaz. How you can implement validation in your approach?

Comment: Hello Maik, 

You should do two types of validation, in my opinion, the first is javascript on the front and the other is the traditional laravel form request validation.

It's a makeover for what's done with JavaScript, but what's done by Laravel is a must-do.
This is how you can do it.
It's in the laravel documentation, but you can still get started quickly like this.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

but the way in my example is a different solution, I think we should ask how request->json is validated in a different way.

Comment: Hello @umutyerebakmaz. Thank you for your answer. Yes I mean how to validate the json object. I haven't tried it yet, but I can imagine that the contents of a json are not validated.

Answer (score 2):

Token

```
let csrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
document.getElementById('_id').addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
    fetch('/method',{
        method : 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({text : e.target.value}),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken.content
        }
    }).then(response =>{
        return response.json()
    }).then( data =>{


    }).catch(error =>console.error(error));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Form, remember to add

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
```

or if using blade buttons:

```
{{ Form::token() }}
```

Adding this anywhere (usually top of body) will be sufficient for all your JavaScript driven buttons. If you are using blade to generate the form, this is automatically added, so don't have to do this.

And change `_token` to `csrf-token` as mentioned by GONG

Comment: its working with _token rather than csrf-token when i make jquery ajax call I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: You're the true hero.

Answer (score 1):

```
function post(id){

        const token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        web = "{{request()->getHttpHost()}}" ;
        url = 'http://' + web + '/metodo';

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRF-Token": token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                key: id
            })
            }).then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(text => {
                return console.log(text);
            }).catch(error => console.error(error));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is what should do a trick for you:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers({
  "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name='_token']").val()
});

var URL = $("#form").attr("action");
  var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
  var myInit = {
   method: 'post',
   headers: myHeaders,
   mode: 'no-cors',
   body: JSON.stringify({
       'group_id': group_id
   };
  var group_id = $(this).val();
  fetch(URL, myInit)
})
.then(function(response){
       return response.json();
})  .then(function(json){



})
.catch(function(error){


});
```

Also it will not work if you have Chrome < 41

Comment: @AbhishekKumar try it now, fixed, it was because of async. At least i can see header x-csrf-token in my plunkr at now. You can see it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/aTBrcb0QLqlPwVudCm2T?p=preview