# Trying to send form and table data using jQuery and Laravel

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel, axios

I am trying to send information to my Laravel controller using jQuery. The issue is I can send my form data well but the table data is not sending; it's just an empty array. Can you please assist me on why I'm having issues sending the data. When I log the data on my backend the form data I can see it but the table data I cant see it. Here is my Javascript code. The table has nothing in it; it's just an empty table.

```
$("#submitForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = [];  // Form data state
    var tableData = []; // Table data state

    // Get form data
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

    // Get table data
    $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function () {
        var row = {};
        row.product_name = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1) input").val();
        row.measurement = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        row.quantity = $(this).find(".quantity input").val(); // Use .val() for input fields
        row.unit_cost = $(this).find(".unit-cost input").val(); // Use .val() for input fields
        row.total_cost = $(this).find(".total-cost input").val(); // Adjust this line based on your HTML structure

        tableData.push(row);
    });

    console.log(tableData);

    // Include table data in the form data
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        // Include table data in the form data
        formData.push({
            name: "table_data",
            value: JSON.stringify(tableData)
        });
    } else {
        console.error("Table data is empty");
        return; // Stop form submission if table data is empty
    }

    // Create a hidden form and submit it
    var hiddenForm = $('<form action="' + $(this).attr('action') + '" method="POST"></form>');

    // Append form data to the hidden form
    formData.forEach(function (field) {
        hiddenForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + field.name + '" value="' + field.value + '">');
    });

    // Append the hidden form to the body and submit
    $('body').append(hiddenForm);
    hiddenForm.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing the `@csrf` tag in your form.
Its used to make sure the request is from a valid user

If you need to do a fetch or ajax request, the csrf token must be present in the headers of the request

```json
"X-CSRF-Token": $('input[name="_token"]').val()
```

[@CSRF Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests)

[Link on how to set csrf token as a header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592834/13353340)